# Wait until network is available in Android emulator (possibly using adb)

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I am doing some tests using standard Google's Android emulator. I have figured out most of the stuff like A) waiting for the device (`adb wait-for-device`) B) for boot to complete (`adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed`), C) unlocking the device (`adb shell input keyevent 82`) and even D) launching an application (`adb shell monkey -p PACKAGE_NAME -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1`).

The one thing I am missing now is **waiting for network**. Basically it takes many seconds after I get `sys.boot_completed` before `3G` shows on top. Even if I can do a `shell ping 10.0.2.2` very early on, the network connectivity for an app is not available before `3G` is shown. If it matters, I am using a proxy (via `-http-proxy` emulator command line argument).

So what I want to do is find a way to make sure emulator has network connectivity before I launch my app. Is there a way to do it with `adb` or any other means? I can't modify the original app.

Comment: Does your adb shell have a ping?  Or you could launch a browser or small custom app to hit a server on your dev machine (via the proxy) and wait for that traffic to be heard.

Comment: If you can use a separate app that tests for interweb connection.  A simple that checks for connection if no connection wait for broadcast receiver when there is interweb.  When it finds interweb it (the connection testing app ) lauches appYourApp.

Comment: Yeah, ping to 10.0.2.2 works very early on when no `3G` is shown. Launching a custom app would probably be perfect except I have no clue how I'd go about building one. I'd need something to request an HTTP resource until the request finally succeeds. Launching a browser sounds like a good idea too except it's not very lightweight. I figured a `wget` would come handy but it is not available.

Answer (score 1):

To find out the current network status check the value of `gsm.network.type` system property. For more detailed information you can parse the output of `dumpsys connectivity`

Comment: I am assuming you mean `getprop gsm.network.type` which returns `UMTS` very early far before `3G` appears. So unfortunately, this won't do it.